Proving the existence of Muhammad saw and the four caliphs
So we have those non Muslims claiming that there is no historical evidence for the existence of our prophet pbuh and the four caliphs ra and they say the quran was written down by a group of people, nauzubillah.
I find this claim strange because we have so many hadiths and in Makkah we also have the grave of our prophet saw.
How can we answer this claim using actual evidence and end this vague argument once and for all?

"Show your proof, if you should be truthful".
The fact is, they were not around during the time of the Prophet, neither were you. For all their talk of "historical evidence", the complete truth of things is known only to Allah.
If they arrogantly believe that they know what transpired fourteen centuries ago, despite of thousands upon thousands of reports to the contrary, the onus is on them to prove themselves. Otherwise, don't waste your time on specious arguments.

Yeah I mean I have found some historical writings from christian sources(as they don't trust hadiths) proving Muhammad saws existence. But I couldn't find any site listing historical evidence for the existence of the four caliphs, that's where I'm currently stuck at.

If those people have accepted any other religion, then they have no stronger reason to accept what they have accepted compared to you, and instead you have something in hand that they don't, and that's Quran, the only miracle of the era of prophets PBUT that has been left to present. This is somewhat the reason why the prophecy ended after all: "وَ مَا أَرْسَلْنَاكَ إِلَّا كَافَّةً لِلنَّاسِ بَشِيرًا وَ نَذِيرًا وَ لَكِنَّ أَكْثَرَ النَّاسِ لَا يَعْلَمُونَ". This is also a correct reasoning against those who believe in no religion at all.
Also, you should think on how the validation of a historical proof is acceptable. To us, Quranic verses (if understood correctly), and Ahadeeth (if authenticate and again understood correctly) are touchstones by which to validate other historical claims, but they lack such books, all the books the historians have are accepted due to not having better more authenticate resources, not because we know they are correct, as far as I have understood. (albeit, there are other methods that historians use, but all are debatable, and religions are not the only histories one ca doubt if is skeptic enough)
